# Why does (false || null) return null, while (null || false) returns false?

Tags: javascript

Why does `false || null` return a different result than `null || false`?

Can I safely rely on `return myVar || false` returning false if myVar is either `null` or `false`, but `true` otherwise?

All Combinations:

`false || null`

null

`null || false`

false

`true || null`

true

`null || true`

true

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x11.11 some potentially useful reading on the spec.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `||` operator in JavaScript doesn't necessarily return `true` or `false`. It's exact behavior is this:

**If the first operand is truthy, it evaluates to the first operand. Otherwise, it evaluates to the second.**

This works as expected given two boolean values, but as you have noticed, you can also use it with any other value. In both of your examples, the first operand is falsey. Thus, both expressions evaluate to the second operand.

---

*Note about one way this is used:* The behavior of `||` is often used to create default arguments:

```js
function foo(optionalArg) {
  optionalArg = optionalArg || "default!";
  console.log(optionalArg);
}

foo("test");
foo();
```

If `optionalArg` is omitted, its values implicitly becomes `undefined`. Because `undefined` is falsey, `undefined || "default!"` evaluates to `"default!"`. Note that this style of default args can backfire if you pass a falsey value, like `0` or `""`. It's more robust to explicitly check for `undefined`. In ECMAScript 6, you can do this with a default value within the parameter list to be more readable:

```js
function foo(optionalArg = "default!") {
  console.log(optionalArg);
}

foo("test");
foo(false);
foo(undefined);
foo();
```

Comment: Although, in that situation, I'd heavily advocate for `function foo(optionalArg = 'default')` for far more semantic, readable code.

Comment: no @David, try `foo(null)` and see that it will not result with `default`

Comment: @Endless you're correct, but you haven't asked for the default argument in that case.  You've explicitly passed in null.

Comment: @qxz thanks for going the extra mile. I appreciated it :).

Answer (score 3):

When you have || between two variables the following happens.

Example: a || b

1. It checks if the a is truthy. If it is then it returns it. If it is not then it checks the next value.
2. If it hasn't returned a value yet then it returns the next value no matter what.

Another way to write this is:

```
if (a) {
    return a;
}
return b;
```

Or:

```
a ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you're doing is:

```
if (myVar) {
  return myVar;
}
return false;
```

If the first part of your expression is truthy, you'll receive the first part.  Otherwise, you'll get the second part.  It's almost like a ternary.

```
firstPart || secondPart
firstPart ? firstPart : secondPart
```

Comment: It doesn't return false if myVar isn't truthy. It returns the other variable.

Comment: @kjonsson In the case of the OP's code, "the other variable" is `false`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to return false then use nullish coalescing operator

```
false ?? null
// result: false
```

Comment: I think this doesn't help OP: please read the title of the question once again.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function foo(optionalArg) {
  optionalArg = optionalArg || "default!";
  console.log(optionalArg);
}

foo(my singingmonster);
foo(1b diamond);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).