# Typescript assigning value to variable with logical operators

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
export class SearchResult {
    id: string;
    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.id = obj && obj.id || null;
    }
}
```

What does `obj && obj.id || null` mean? I don't get this syntax.

Comment: It checks if object exists and id is present on that object or null. that seems to be some interesting javascript in that, there is a similar question that perhaps answers your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814333/why-does-false-null-return-null-while-null-false-returns-false/40814362)

Comment: Right, so null seems to be the default value, but how does javascript knows what to return between obj && obj.id? it is because obj.id is a property?

Comment: @PeterNguyen Did my answer help?

Comment: @BenSmith yes thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whilst your code is using Typescript, this question actually concerns JavaScript.

In JavaScript:

`true && expression`

will cause the `expression` to be evalauted.

As for:

`false && expression`

this will evaluate to false causing the `expression` to not be evaulated.

Hence in your constructor, if obj is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (e.g. neither null or undefined) the expression will be evaluated, in this case accessing the obj.id and assigning its value to this.id. If obj is not truthy, then it will evaluate to false, and the null value will get assigned to this.id.

This technique is often used in React, see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) for an example.

Comment: WOW! Somehow, this has evaded me for years! I've always thought `true && expression` evaluated to `true`. I guess because usually when I use this concept, I'm trying to use the value as truthy and it works

Comment: @Scrimothy it's a really useful technique for writing succinct code :) I guess one will only consider it succinct though if they understand what's going on!